# Sending AJAX Request from Controller back to View (CakePHP 2.0+)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to send ajax data back to the view, but its not working

Here is my controller:

```
    $this->autoRender = 0;
    $this->layout = 'ajax';

    $data = $this->HostingAccount->HostPackage->find('list',array('conditions' => array(
                    'HostPackage.host_id' => $this->data['HostingAccount']['host_id'])));

    //can't get access to $options in my View
    set('options',$data);
```

In the default.ctp I have:

```
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('inline' => true));
```

In the ajax.ctp:

```
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

I've tried playing around with different settings like commenting out $this->autoRender and just trying to access $options from default view instead of ajax and it just doesn't let me get the data from it.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: AJAX by definition is more than one single request, you cannot return the data from the controller to the original view - its a second and asynchronous request - you need to send it using JSON for example and then use this response in the JS in the original view that fired the AJAX request. Read [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/) and see the live examples linked there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by AJAX being more than one single request, I've never seen that definition before anywhere, and yes it is possible to send the data back to the view and I just figured out how simply by creating the view for the function which handles the AJAX request.

Comment: You are still sending it back from the secondary (AJAX) request to the primary (GET) request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was missing a View for the function which was handling the AJAX request, by simply creating a View ajax_populate.ctp for the function ajax_populate() in the controller I was able to retreive the data from that view and work with it further:

Controller:

```
        public function ajax_populate() {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';

        $data = $this->Domain->HostingAccount->HostPackage->find('list',array('conditions' => array(
                        'HostPackage.host_id' => $this->data['Domain']['host_id'])));

        $this->set('options', $data);
    }
```

View:

```
<?php 
echo "<div><select>";
foreach($options as $key => $val){
    echo "<option value='$key'>$val</option>";
}
echo "</select></div>";
```

Original View (from which the ajax is called):

```
       echo $this->Js->get('#DomainHostId')->event('change',$this->Js->request('ajax_populate',
                    array('method' => 'POST',
                          'async' => true,
                          'update' => '#host_packages',
                          'dataExpression' => true,
                          'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
                             'isForm' => true,
                             'inline' => true
                            ))
                          //'evalScripts' => true
                         )));
```

?>

HTML: (div)

```
   <div id="host_packages"></div>
```